# Shift column in pandas based on conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to shift a column in a dataframe by creating a conditional statement, however I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There's about 1000+ rows in this dataframe, but here's a sample.

Original dataframe

```
Price Range    str_num     str_dir        str          str_sfx      city              zip
200 - 300k     123         Fake           St           Boulder      80304            None
300 - 400k     456         Main           St           Erie         80123            None
300 - 400k     789         E              Lolly        St           Boulder          80302
300 - 400k     999         N              Home         Ave          Lafayette        80027
```

Now what I want to do is say if the column `str_dir` doesn't have N, E, W, S in it, shift it to the right, fill the rest with NaN. Here's my code so far.

```
mylist = ['N','E','W','S']
a=df[~df['str_dir'].isin(mylist)].shift(periods=-1, axis='columns', fill_value=np.NaN)
out_df=a.combine_first(df)
```

However, when I run this code I get this dataframe.

```
Price Range    str_num     str_dir        str           city              zip
123            Fake        St             Boulder       80304            None
456            Main        St             Erie          80123            None
300 - 400k     789         E              Lolly         Boulder          80302
300 - 400k     999         N              Home          Lafayette        80027
```

What I'm looking for is this

```
Price Range    str_num     str_dir        str           str_sfx              city              zip
200 - 300k     123         NaN            Fake          St                  Boulder          80304
300 - 400k     456         NaN            Main          St                  Erie             80123
300 - 400k     789         E              Lolly         St                  Boulder          80302
300 - 400k     999         N              Home          Ave                 Lafayette        80027
```

Comment: You generally **don't** want to do this, this is an antipattern that your `read_csv()` statement mishandled the separators (or that the CSV separators are not correct). Are you able to go back to the `read_csv()` that malfunctioned, and let's fix it instead?

Comment: I essentially split one column that contained the whole address by whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to create a boolean mask `m`, then use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask `m` to select a rows and columns of dataframe that needed to be shifted using [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) along `axis=1`:

```
m = ~df['str_dir'].isin(mylist)
df.loc[m, 'str_dir':] = df.loc[m, 'str_dir':].shift(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
  Price Range  str_num str_dir    str str_sfx       city    zip
0  200 - 300k      123     NaN   Fake      St    Boulder  80304
1  300 - 400k      456     NaN   Main      St       Erie  80123
2  300 - 400k      789       E  Lolly      St    Boulder  80302
3  300 - 400k      999       N   Home     Ave  Lafayette  80027
```